# Grammar for Java's annotations

Tags: java, annotations, grammar, bnf, ebnf

Is there a BNF or EBNF that describes the grammar for Java's annotations?

Comment: Any particular annotations?  I expect that the answer is no, btw.

Comment: Just in general - I was trying to look at how it handles the parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authoritative source for Java-related grammar, is, of course, the JLS.

[JLS 18.1 The Grammar of the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html#18.1)

```
Annotations:
        Annotation [Annotations]

Annotation:
        @ TypeName [( [Identifier =] ElementValue)]

ElementValue:
        ConditionalExpression
        Annotation
        ElementValueArrayInitializer

... rest ommitted
```

Answer (score 1):

`/* Annotation syntax follows. */

Annotation  ::=   NormalAnnotation
  |   SingleMemberAnnotation
  |   MarkerAnnotation
NormalAnnotation  ::=   "@" Name "(" ( MemberValuePairs )? ")"
MarkerAnnotation  ::=   "@" Name
SingleMemberAnnotation  ::=   "@" Name "(" MemberValue ")"
MemberValuePairs  ::=   MemberValuePair ( "," MemberValuePair )*
MemberValuePair   ::=    "=" MemberValue
MemberValue   ::=   Annotation
  |   MemberValueArrayInitializer
  |   ConditionalExpression
MemberValueArrayInitializer   ::=   "{" ( MemberValue ( "," MemberValue )* ( "," )? )? "}"

/* Annotation Types. */

AnnotationTypeDeclaration   ::=   "@" "interface"  AnnotationTypeBody
AnnotationTypeBody  ::=   "{" ( AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration )* "}"
AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration   ::=   Modifiers ( Type  "(" ")" ( DefaultValue )? ";" | ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration | EnumDeclaration | AnnotationTypeDeclaration | FieldDeclaration )
  |   ( ";" )
DefaultValue  ::=   "default" MemberValue` [from here](http://infoether.com/~tom/java.bnf). Also see his [blog post](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/juniordeveloper/2009/06/lovely-svg-railroad-diagrams-with-javacc-and-clapham.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java language grammar

1. Any Type may be prefixed by [Annotations]:

   `Type:
     [Annotations] Identifier [TypeArguments] {. Identifier [TypeArguments]} {[]}
     [Annotations] BasicType`
2. To permit annotations on levels of an array (in declarations, not constructors), change “{[]}” to “{[Annotations] []}”. (This was abstracted out as “BracketsOpt” in the 2nd edition of the JLS [GJSB00].) For example:

`Type:
      [Annotations] Identifier [TypeArguments]{ . Identifier [TypeArguments]} {[Annotations] []}
      [Annotations] BasicType`

`Also permit annotations on varargs (...):
  FormalParameterDeclsRest:
      VariableDeclaratorId [, FormalParameterDecls]
      [Annotations] ... VariableDeclaratorId`

3. Annotations may appear on the receiver type by changing uses of “FormalParameters” (in all 5 places it appears in the grammar) to “FormalParameters [Annotations]”. For example:

   `VoidMethodDeclaratorRest:
     FormalParameters [Annotations] [throws QualifiedIdentifierList] ( MethodBody | ; )`

Answer (score 0):

This is the ANTLRv4 grammar for Java Annotations (usage and definition) from the official [ANTLR GitHub repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java/JavaParser.g4#L300-L364).

Annotation usage grammar:

```
altAnnotationQualifiedName
    : (IDENTIFIER DOT)* '@' IDENTIFIER
    ;


annotation
    : ('@' qualifiedName | altAnnotationQualifiedName) ('(' ( elementValuePairs | elementValue )? ')')?
    ;


elementValuePairs
    : elementValuePair (',' elementValuePair)*
    ;


elementValuePair
    : IDENTIFIER '=' elementValue
    ;


elementValue
    : expression
    | annotation
    | elementValueArrayInitializer
    ;


elementValueArrayInitializer
    : '{' (elementValue (',' elementValue)*)? (',')? '}'
    ;
```

Annotation declaration grammar:

```
annotationTypeDeclaration
    : '@' INTERFACE IDENTIFIER annotationTypeBody
    ;


annotationTypeBody
    : '{' (annotationTypeElementDeclaration)* '}'
    ;


annotationTypeElementDeclaration
    : modifier* annotationTypeElementRest
    | ';' // this is not allowed by the grammar, but apparently allowed by the actual compiler
    ;


annotationTypeElementRest
    : typeType annotationMethodOrConstantRest ';'
    | classDeclaration ';'?
    | interfaceDeclaration ';'?
    | enumDeclaration ';'?
    | annotationTypeDeclaration ';'?
    ;


annotationMethodOrConstantRest
    : annotationMethodRest
    | annotationConstantRest
    ;


annotationMethodRest
    : IDENTIFIER '(' ')' defaultValue?
    ;


annotationConstantRest
    : variableDeclarators
    ;


defaultValue
    : DEFAULT elementValue
    ;
```